# Definitions of locally contractible spaces

Tags: general-topology

I have seen two definitions of locally contractible spaces:

1. (Wikipedia) A topological space $X$ is locally contractible if every point has arbitrarily small contractible neighborhoods.
2. (nLab) A topological space $X$ is locally contractible if every point has arbitrarily small **open** contractible neighborhoods.

Clearly, Definition 2 implies Definitions 1. But I don't know how to prove the converse.

Q: Are these two definitions equivalent?

Comment: In many books neighborhoods are defined as open sets anyway.

Comment: @Mark Yes, but here a neighborhood is not assumed to be open.

Comment: Another definition is stated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3926041/4280), That's the one recall being taught too.